# Union of Span in Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I didn't get how union of span in vector spaces work.
So, what I think is if $U = \{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\}$ and $V = \{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\}$, does $U \cup V$ mean $\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\}$?

If so, does $\langle U \cup V\rangle$ mean $\langle U\rangle+\langle V\rangle$? Is there any way of proving so?

Comment: What did you try? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask